# Blue dot appearing to left of user list

Tags: javascript, node.js, material-ui

I have this `render` function:

```
render() {
    const {classes} = this.props
    return (
      <Paper className={classes.root} elevation={4}>
        <Typography type="title" className={classes.title}>
          All Users
        </Typography>
        <List dense>
         {this.state.users.map((item, i) => {
          const photoUrl = item._id
              ? `/api/users/photo/${item._id}?${new Date().getTime()}`
              : '/api/users/defaultphoto'
          return <Link to={"/user/" + item._id} key={i}>
                    <ListItem button>
                      <ListItemAvatar>
                        <Avatar src={photoUrl} className={classes.bigAvatar}/>
                      </ListItemAvatar>
                      <ListItemText primary={item.name}/>
                      <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                      <IconButton>
                          <ArrowForward/>
                      </IconButton>
                      </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                    </ListItem>
                 </Link>
               })
             }
        </List>
      </Paper>
    )
  }
}
```

When I Initially load the page the below blue dot appears to the left of each user:

[image]

If I then click a link to another page and then the browser back arrow to return to the Users page the user list appears without the blue dot:

[image]

I would prefer if the blue dot never appears. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you specify in your question which library you're using? There are many implementations of the Material UI spec for React, and your particular issue might be specific to the library you're using.

Comment: Hi @err1100, I'mn not sure what you mean. This is the material-ui I'm using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui/v/1.0.0-beta.43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume somewhere in the nested components you have a `li` of some sort.

The dots are from html list bullet points and can be removed by adding the following css:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none !important;
}
```

If the component is a part of the Material-UI library, you might need to add !important

Comment: Possibly. I'll have to look and see if it's there.

Comment: If there is a class name you gave to the entire list then can just do something like `.myuserlist * { list-style-type: none !important; }`, then it will catch any lists rendered by the material-ui library.

Comment: I can't find any `li` although I did some reading and found that the default `component` for `ListItem` is `li`. Perhaps that's where it's getting it. Even if that is the case, I don't know where `list-style-type: none !important;` would go.

Comment: You put it in your css file

Comment: I haven't changed anything since my last comment but the blue dot no longer appears. Maybe something was cached and a browser restart cleared it. Happy that this is sorted though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem :) Dont forget to mark it as answered so others know it solved the problem

Answer (score 9):

I faced the same problem today using ListItem component from react material ui v4.6.0.

The default list style type value of disc will be displayed if "ListItemSecondaryAction" component is used as the last child of "ListItem" component.

According to the [React Material UI Docs](https://material-ui.com/api/list-item/), the value of ContainerComponent prop will be set to 'li' when ListItemSecondaryAction is used as the last child.

Changing the value of ContainerComponent prop to other elementType such as 'div' fixed the issue.

```
        <ListItem button ContainerComponent="div">
      <ListItemAvatar>
        <Avatar src={photoUrl} className={classes.bigAvatar} />
      </ListItemAvatar>
      <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
      <ListItemSecondaryAction>
        <IconButton>
          <ArrowForward />
        </IconButton>
      </ListItemSecondaryAction>
    </ListItem>
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me. My issue was I was using AutoSizer within List (from react-virtualized) which blocks some Material-UI css from applying, causing the bullet points to appear.